# OpenLayers getting OSM from local server

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers

I have successfully installed OSM tile server on a local server. I verified operation using direct calls

```
http://server_ip/hot/z/x/y.png
```

I setup a page with OpenLayers 5.2.0. The layer init :

```
osm = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM({
        opaque: false,
        url: 'http://server_ip/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
        //url: 'http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
    })
});
```

When I use the `a.tile.openstreetmap.org` it works ok, but shows blank tiles on my local server call.

I verified the call to my server using wireshark, http request and reply. The return of HTTP are the required tiles (verified by saving them to disk). But OpenLayers is showing blank.

Does OpenLayers expect other parameters (in layer init code) when not specifically using osm server? (or timeout problem since my server is slower?)

Comment: If you are not using the default OSM url if may be better to use ol.source.XYZ instead of ol.source.OSM.  As well as defaulting the url and attribution ol.source.OSM sets crossOrigin anonymous (which isn't needed unless you are accessing the canvas and will cause problems if the server isn't CORS enabled).

Comment: I just changed (ol.source.OSM) to (ol.source.XYZ) and it works. Thanks. Any side effects, moving from OSM to XYZ?

Comment: could you move to answer to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using the default OSM url if may be better to use `ol.source.XYZ` instead of `ol.source.OSM`. `ol.source.OSM` extents `ol.source.XYZ` by setting default values if the following are not defined:

```
attributions
attributionsCollapsible (new in 5.3.0)
crossOrigin
maxZoom
url
```

The OSM default of crossOrigin anonymous when combined with a different url which isn't CORS enabled may result in tiles not loading.

Comment: thanks Mike. yes, indeed, it works with ol.source.OSM when I added (crossOrigin: null,).